# Сhange the text color of the selected item in list view (Kotlin, Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, onclicklistener, textcolor

I have a list view in my app. How can I change the text color of the selected item?

For example, I select some list item. Its text color should be changed from black to gray.
Then I select another item. Its text color should also be changed from black to gray, but the text color of the first element should turn black again.

I tried the following code, but I got an exception:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method '`void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)`' on a null object reference

**QuestionActivity.kt:**

```
var answersList = arrayOf("about", "against", "for", "by")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question)

    val selection= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.options)
    val lv = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.variants)
    val prodAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mytextview, answersList)
    lv.adapter = prodAdapter

    lv.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
     val selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
     selection.setText(selectedItem)
     selection.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
    }}
```

**activity_question.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/variants"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="254dp" tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and **mytextview.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/options"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
      android:textSize="20dp"
      android:textColor="#000000"
/>
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to use selectors. Something like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color ="@color/selected_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color ="@color/pressed_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color ="@color/default_color"/>

</selector>
```

And then use your selector in the item XML file :

`android:textColor="@color/text_selector"`

You can have more information [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource)

Comment: Thank you for your response @cesarmarch, but I had already tried the similar solution and it didn't help. The color changes only while clicking on an item. When you stop pressing the item, the color return to its default color. And I need the color to remain different until I click on another list item.

Comment: I think you should manually set your item as selected to keep the color. And, same thing, manually unselect it when another is selected.